# Line break in textOutputField

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

here is my code. i get the data from web and store in bufval and print textoutputfield but we require a line break a specific position in the textoutput field if we use line break in php page where we get the data the output is show msg and attach this (
).

String strResult = new String(bufVal);
                                synchronized (UiApplication.getEventLock()) 
                                {
                                textOutputField.setText(strResult);
                                }

Answer (score 1):

why don't you try add "\n" character where you want the line break to be.